# how to get number of rows in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I want to select 2 minimum elements from every column of matrix. How to can display number of row?
input:

```
    a1 a2 a3
    --------
b1  2  4  8
b2  8  5  3
b3  1  5  9
```

output:

```
 a1 a2 a3         a1  a2  a3
 --------         ----------
 1  4  3    =>    b3  b1  b2 
 2  5  8          b1  b2  b1
```

my code:

```
for i = 1:3
   MINN(:,i)=getNElements(distance(i,:), 1);
end

function [smallestNElements smallestNIdx] = getNElements(A, n)
   [ASorted AIdx] = sort(A);
   smallestNElements = ASorted(1:n);
   smallestNIdx = AIdx(1:n);
end
```

Comment: What's the desired input and output, exactly? How are the two values selected from each column? What are those `a1` etc?

Comment: my input is a matrix with rows of a1-a3 and columns of b1-b3. The values selected by getNElements().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess, is this what you want to do?

```
x = [2  4  8; 8  5  3; 1  5  9]; % data
n = 2; % desired number of smallest values per column
[y, ind] = sort(x,1); % sort each column and get indices of that sorting
y = y(1:n,:); % keep n smallest
ind = ind(1:n,:); % keep their indices
```

Results:

```
y =
     1     4     3
     2     5     8

ind =
     3     1     2
     1     2     1
```